# Quit all Safari Web Content processes at once?

Tags: macos, safari

The biggest RAM hog on my computer is my unhealthy habit of keeping too many Safari tabs open. Even when I close them, their associated processes don't necessarily disappear if those processes were also supporting still-active tabs. I know that quitting a Safari Web Content process in Activity Monitor force-refreshes the websites that that process was supporting, but is there a convenient way to do this to all of the Safari Web Content processes at once? I know that restarting Safari works, but I'm hoping there's a faster way.

Comment: Is the Close all windows not working for you ? there is even a shortcut for it.

Comment: @Buscar웃 I don't want to close all the windows. I want to force-refresh all of the pages by quitting their Safari Web Content processes, which would in turn free up a decent amount of RAM.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. So the cmd+option+e should clear the caches.

Comment: and the cmd+r should reload

Comment: ⌘-Option-E isn't doing anything for me.

Comment: then try the holding the ctrl and click on any tab and select reload all tabs ?